# Rust closures from factory functions

Tags: rust

I have some Rust code I'm trying to get working but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
fn main() {
    let names = vec!["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    let print = printer(names);
    let result = print();
    println!("{}", result);
    do_other_thing(names.as_slice());
}

fn printer(names: Vec<&str>) -> Box<Fn() -> String> {
    Box::new(move || {
        let text = String::new();
        for name in names {
            text = text + name;
        }
        text
    })
}

fn do_other_thing(names: &[&str]) {}
```

This compiles with:

```
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/main.rs:10:14: 16:6 names:std::vec::Vec<&str>]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:10:5
   |
10 |       Box::new(move || {
   |  _____^ starting here...
11 | |         let text = String::new();
12 | |         for name in names {
13 | |             text = text + name;
14 | |         }
15 | |         text
16 | |     })
   | |______^ ...ending here
   |
   = note: type must outlive the static lifetime
```

I have a vague idea of what's going on.  It looks like there's a chance the closure will outlive the `names` parameter. I can annotate as `'static` but that doesn't feel right and even then I'd like to not move the vector so that `do_other_thing` works. I need to copy somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that `names` must outlive the static lifetime, this is because the boxed `Fn` has static lifetime. You have two options:

1. Add the `'static` lifetime to `names`:

   ```
   fn printer(names: Vec<&'static str>) -> Box<Fn() -> String>{
       Box::new(move|| {
           // ...
       })
   }
   ```
2. Change the lifetime of the boxed `Fn` to match the `names` lifetime:

   ```
   fn printer<'a>(names: Vec<&'a str>) -> Box<Fn() -> String + 'a>{
       Box::new(move|| {
           // ...
       })
   }
   ```

Note that the body of closure needs to be adjusted and that you are giving the ownership of `names` to `printer`, so you cannot use `names` in `do_other_thing`. Here is a fixed version:

```
fn main() {
    let names = vec!["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    let print = printer(&names);
    let result = print();
    println!("{}", result);
    do_other_thing(names.as_slice());
}

fn printer<'a>(names: &'a Vec<&str>) -> Box<Fn() -> String + 'a>{
    Box::new(move || {
        // this is more idiomatic
        // map transforms &&str to &str
        names.iter().map(|s| *s).collect()
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The + 'a to tie the closure lifetime was exactly what I was looking for.